# How would I break up and extract an array from an array-of-hashes in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, hash

for example:

```
[ (id=>1, email=>'tim@tim.com', name=>'tim'),
  (id=>2, email=>'joe@joe.com', name=>'joe'),
  (id=>3, email=>'dan@dan.com', name=>'dan') ]
```

How can I extract the email column and put it in its own array?

Comment: Do you *have* to start with an array-of-hashes? If the array-of-hashes is just an intermediary step to get the email addresses, then I'd say there's a more straightforward and elegant solution to your problem.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Let's call your array `users`. You can do this:

```
users.map{|u| u[:email]}
```

This looks at the hashes one by one, calling them `u`, extracts the `:email` key, and returns the results in a new array of user emails.

Comment: You could also use users.collect{|u| u[:email]}, collect is an alias for map, which might be easier for some people (those who don't have a functional background).

Answer (score 3):

```
[ {id=>1, email=>'tim@tim.com', name=>'tim'},
  {id=>2, email=>'joe@joe.com', name=>'joe'},
  {id=>3, email=>'dan@dan.com', name=>'dan'} ].map{|h| h['email']}
```